# div problems in css/html

Tags: css, html

```
<style ="text/css">
.asd123 {
height: 100px;
width: 900px;
margin: auto;
border: 3px dashed black;
}
.asd123_text {
font-family: Garamond;
font-size: 62px;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="asd123">

        <p class="asd123_text" style="padding-top:-50px; text-align:center; position:absolute;">generictext</p>

</div>
```

How can I make the paragraph text stack over the div or something?

I am pretty new to css and html but I do understand some of it, however css is starting to get really stupid

Comment: What do you mean by "stack over the div"?

Answer (score 1):

just  remove the styles you have give, just make `margin:0`

```
            <div class="asd123">

    <p class="asd123_text" style="">generictext</p>
```

and css

```
   .asd123 {
      height: 100px;
      width: 900px;
     margin: auto;
     border: 3px dashed black;
     }
     .asd123_text {
         font-family: Garamond;
         font-size: 62px;
         margin:0    ;
         text-align:center
          }
```

Comment: thanks @Rhea but how can i move the text down a few px's? padding wont work

Comment: you can set the margin accordingly. or just `margin-top`  `margin:0` was necessary because `p` tag adds default margin of its own, and that is why your `p` was going below the div